# "Javac" and "java" commands seems not to get updated code

Tags: java, debugging, javac

my project structure is something like

```
src -
     model
           -RequestManager.java
Application.java
```

Now even after making changes to RequestManager.java when I run command javac Application.java followed by java Application those changes are not reflected. But when I run it through debug option in intellij it works fine. why are those changes not reflecting in ideal case?

Comment: Could you write out the full commands you are using?

Comment: javac Application.java and then java Application

Comment: Is the Application.class in the same directory as the Application.java file?

Comment: yes @NomadMaker